Delete operation using COLLSPAN takes too long to complete
I have a huge collection with over one hundred million documents and each document has a timestamp field (a long) containing the timespan of the event.
Sometimes we need to purge this collection, maintaining only the most recent documents, let's say the from last month.
So my application (Java) does delete operation and this operation is a bit slow. A close look to the operation i see that it's doing a COLLSCAN.
{
      type: 'op',
      host: 'myserver:27017',
      desc: 'conn1402',
      connectionId: 1402,
      client: '10.101.74.5:57972',
      clientMetadata: {
        driver: { name: 'mongo-java-driver|sync', version: '4.8.2' },
        os: {
          type: 'Linux',
          name: 'Linux',
          architecture: 'amd64',
          version: '3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64'
        },
        platform: 'Java/Red Hat, Inc./1.8.0_292-b10'
      },
      active: true,
      currentOpTime: '2024-09-27T18:21:18.043+00:00',
      effectiveUsers: [ { user: 'live', db: 'live' } ],
      threaded: true,
      opid: 13882499,
      lsid: {
        id: UUID('db3c7afc-61e6-44f4-b370-8780ec9945d3'),
        uid: Binary.createFromBase64('VvWgJA6DwjHnyaWi2eVO3B/hb1/6f9RI7ui47NU9J2g=', 0)
      },
      secs_running: Long('1577'),
      microsecs_running: Long('1577944218'),
      op: 'remove',
      ns: 'live_time.events.rig_second_od2_1_hour_replay',
      redacted: false,
      command: {
        q: {
          timestamp: { '$gte': Long('0'), '$lt': Long('1726854900023') }
        },
        limit: 0
      },
      planSummary: 'COLLSCAN',
      numYields: 92653,
      locks: {
        ParallelBatchWriterMode: 'r',
        FeatureCompatibilityVersion: 'w',
        ReplicationStateTransition: 'w',
        Global: 'w',
        Database: 'w',
        Collection: 'w'
      },
      waitingForLock: false,
      lockStats: {
        ParallelBatchWriterMode: { acquireCount: { r: Long('92654') } },
        FeatureCompatibilityVersion: { acquireCount: { w: Long('92654') } },
        ReplicationStateTransition: { acquireCount: { w: Long('92654') } },
        Global: { acquireCount: { w: Long('92654') } },
        Database: { acquireCount: { w: Long('92654') } },
        Collection: { acquireCount: { w: Long('92654') } }
      },
      waitingForFlowControl: false,
      flowControlStats: { acquireCount: Long('92654') }
    }, 

The collection has an index on timestamp field.
Is this the normal behaviour?
Since this is a delete operation Mongodb chooses to do a COLLSCAN because it has to phisically remove the document anyway, so a IXSCAN doesn't make sense. Is my feeling correct, or there is something i could do to improve the purge performance?

Looks like you delete a major portion of the collection. In this case the COLLSCAN is the most efficient one. Infex scans are useful when you need to find (update/delete) only a small subset of all documents.
Maybe it is an option to make a copy, i.e. select only the data you need and $out it to a new collection and then drop entire collection with the old data.
